# Linear regression in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, statistics

Please help me figure this out, spent hours with regr_slope and others regr_...

There are some values in value column, which are blank (null), I need to fill them in using linear regression.

Each feature partition will represent a graph, which always starts with (0,0) and ends with (1,1), which represents 100%. So in my case coordinates are (pct, value)

We have a random set of points per each feature, so I assume there will be a need for several different linear regressions calculated to accomplish this.

Here is the dataset:

```
 pct  | cat_id1 | feature1 | cat_id2 | value
------+---------+----------+---------+-------
 0.05 |       6 | FEATURE2 |       6 |  0.08
 0.10 |       6 | FEATURE2 |         |
 0.15 |       6 | FEATURE2 |         |
 0.20 |       6 | FEATURE2 |         |
 0.25 |       6 | FEATURE2 |         |
 0.30 |       6 | FEATURE2 |         |
 0.35 |       6 | FEATURE2 |         |
 0.40 |       6 | FEATURE2 |         |
 0.45 |       6 | FEATURE2 |         |
 0.50 |       6 | FEATURE2 |       6 |  0.82
 0.55 |       6 | FEATURE2 |       6 |  0.87
 0.60 |       6 | FEATURE2 |         |
 0.65 |       6 | FEATURE2 |       6 |  0.90
 0.70 |       6 | FEATURE2 |         |
 0.75 |       6 | FEATURE2 |         |
 0.80 |       6 | FEATURE2 |         |
 0.85 |       6 | FEATURE2 |         |
 0.90 |       6 | FEATURE2 |         |
 0.95 |       6 | FEATURE2 |         |
 1.00 |       6 | FEATURE2 |       6 |  1.00
 0.05 |       6 | FEATURE1 |       6 |  0.04
 0.10 |       6 | FEATURE1 |         |
 0.15 |       6 | FEATURE1 |         |
 0.20 |       6 | FEATURE1 |         |
 0.25 |       6 | FEATURE1 |         |
 0.30 |       6 | FEATURE1 |         |
 0.35 |       6 | FEATURE1 |         |
 0.40 |       6 | FEATURE1 |         |
 0.45 |       6 | FEATURE1 |         |
 0.50 |       6 | FEATURE1 |         |
 0.55 |       6 | FEATURE1 |         |
 0.60 |       6 | FEATURE1 |         |
 0.65 |       6 | FEATURE1 |         |
 0.70 |       6 | FEATURE1 |         |
 0.75 |       6 | FEATURE1 |         |
 0.80 |       6 | FEATURE1 |       6 |  0.86
 0.85 |       6 | FEATURE1 |       6 |  0.91
 0.90 |       6 | FEATURE1 |       6 |  0.96
 0.95 |       6 | FEATURE1 |         |
 1.00 |       6 | FEATURE1 |       6 |  1.00
(40 rows)
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is your question?  If you know the points (0,0) and (1,1), then there is nothing left to do.  Two points define a line.

Comment: @jjanes: thank you for responding. As I've mentioned my coordinates are (pct, value). So I have to figure out multiple "lines". For example in my data in FEATURE2 partition 1st line should go through (0.05,0.08) to (0.5,0.82), 2nd line from (0.55,0.87) to (0.65,0.90) and the 3rd one from (0.65,0.90) to (1,1). Hope it makes it clearer

Comment: Ah, so what you want is piecewise linear.  Because each piece is defined by two points, you don't need regression, just arithmetic.  You can probably do this using windows functions and lead and lag and a self join, but that would be a mess and I would probably use a procedural language instead.

Comment: Yeah, after poking at it I did exactly that. The sql doesn't look pretty, but it worked.